# Android SMS app Crashes when received sms contains lots of numbers

Tags: java, android

i have written the following code to get the received sms in phone
        package com.example.recieveandsendsms;

```
    public class IncomingSms extends BroadcastReceiver{

        final SmsManager sms=SmsManager.getDefault();
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


               Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
                SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
                String str = "";            
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                    //---retrieve the SMS message received---
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
                    for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                        str = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();

                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Following is my manifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.recieveandsendsms"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS">
        </uses-permission>
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
          <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>




        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name="com.example.recieveandsendsms.MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

             <receiver android:name="com.example.recieveandsendsms.IncomingSms">
            <intent-filter android:priority="999">
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

it works fine when I receive the normal message
means example Ex1: He was not angry or upset I was remember
was drawn on with us just a little thing.

when message in Ex1 comes it works fine

but when Ex2: UB 9000000000 9787878787-asghkajhsgk kjashgkas

but when sms like Ex2 compes the application crashes i am not able get what is wrong the message in Ex2

Please anyone can help me to tell where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library version for reading and writing data was mismatch so it was crashing and it was not giving any error :(